# looking for a tag script for my website

Tags: php, javascript, seo, tags

I'm not asking someone to make a script for me, only to point me to a known script.

A lot of websites have tags on the end of a article with important keyword links, mosly those are scripts used in CMS systems.

I'm looking for the same sort of script but for a "normal" website without cms

Does anyone knows a script like that?

Comment: At least tell us the language you're using.  Also, features like this make more sense integrated into the rest of your design (including database schema).

Comment: What language? C, PHP, .Net, python, scheme, javascript? Something else?

Comment: I'm sorry, php or js would be great!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this could be called via JavaScript http://www.tocloud.com/javascript_cloud_generator.html, and would do exactly what you need. See example on the URL

Comment: All that does is parse a text box into a bunch of variously sized text.  What he wants will require server (incl. database support).

Comment: This is indeed not what I ment, this service has no seo effect on my website I think.